# iPhone memory management

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory

I don't understand this exactly.

if I write:

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber initWithInteger: 5];
```

do I have to release it?

Is this the same as:
NSNumber *number= [NSNumber alloc];

?

Comment: [Related and important](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1). If you haven't already, you **must** read it.

Answer (score 5):

You wouldn't call `NSNumber *number = [NSNumber initWithInteger: 5];` because `NSNumber` does not respond to `+ initWithInteger:`. You actually need to call both `+alloc` and `-initWithInteger:`, like this:

```
NSNumber *number = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:5];
```

Then you will have to release it later; for every alloc call you make, you should also make a call to release.

---

Alternatively, you could get an autoreleased `NSNumber` using the following class method:

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:5];
```

Methods like this return an *autoreleased* object, which means that you do not need to release it yourself later.

Comment: +1, no such method indeed. Another way is : `[[NSNumber numberWithInteger:5] retain];`

Comment: and if I just enter NSInteger *integer = 5;
do I have to release it?

Comment: @Wikiboo `NSInteger` is just a plain old type (similar to `int`, `float`, `double` and `char`). It's not a class. It's not a subclass of `NSNumber` either. And `NSInteger *integer = 5;` is wrong: you assign a constant to a pointer, which you should never do except for `NULL`, `nil` and `Nil` (remove the asterisk and you are fine). No, you should never release nor free a POD (plain old type), because they are pre-allocated by the compiler, not at runtime.

Comment: @Wikiboo - NSUInteger is a base type, no memory managment, but you should name your var...

Answer (score 2):

"The general rule of thumb is: If you alloc, copy, or new, memory management's on you."

I'd add retain to this as well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no class method named "*+(id)initWithInteger:*" in *NSNumber* class. That should be "*+(id)numberWithInteger:*"

You should not release it. Constructors like "*[NSNumber numberWith...*"  are called **convenient constructors**. They return **autoreleased objects**. So, you don't have to worry about releasing them.

Comment: Careful, he's writing "initWithInteger"

Comment: God! I didn't notice it. Thank you ;-)